# What kind of configuration file is this?

Tags: linux, unix, configuration-files

I have the following config file, it was taken from a Unix/Linux like networking device.

I am trying to figure out if there is a name for such a kind of config file so that I can re-use an existing java/other library to parse it.

The config file content is as follows:

```
config site element Open
  instance Server001
    exit
config site module BTS Console Management enable
config site element Server001
    type TMonitor
    param alarmSource elements
    param criticalInputs 21
    param warningInputs 0
    param informationalInputs 4
component Server001
    param normalState close
    param description 'voltageFail'
    param discrete 'input 0/1'
    param debounceTime 0
    exit
component Server001
    param normalState close
    param description 'Dark Mode'
    param discrete 'input 0/2'
    exit
```

From the first glance it resembles a list of commands, but then you have tab indentation as well.

so

```
config site element Server001
    type TMonitor
```

would translate to

```
config site element Server001 type TMonitor
```

I would be interested in knowing the configuration file kind, ex: is it JSON, XML, TOML etc?

Comment: I can confirm , This is definitely not a log file, the file name is `device-config` and changing the file has effects

Comment: What is the device make and model?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I just have SSH/SFTP access to it, no unix commands run on it, though the config file looks very similar to this https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/cmd_ref/s5.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a Westell configuration file / list of commands.

See http://support.westell.com/documents/Technical-Job-Aides/Westell_Troubleshooting_Procedure_v7.pdf

Comment: My 5 min search resulted also resulted in [westell doccument](http://support.westell.com/Documents/Release-Notes/Modules_245_xrn.pdf). Looks like these are commands executed on networking devices, like [RMX - 3200](https://studylib.net/doc/8150914/remote-rmx-3200-command-reference-guide-for).